# How to display json data into datatable and in tabs?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I am trying to display json data into php.

Can you tell me how can I sort this into a datatable also with tabs?

as  I am going to Display this into each tab as well Like Bitcoin List with Icon and text and  ETH list with icon and Text etc 
so they can pick what ever coin they like then it shows them the faucet list  for that coin

So i need This for each Tab with Datatable

Also yes I looked Google why I would not be posting here

**faucetlist.json**

```js
[{"name": "Bitcoin",
  "shorthand": "BTC",
  "faucets": [
        {"faucet name":"gr8 Faucet",
        "minutes": "5",
        "reward": "~3000",
        "claim": "http://namefaucet.net"},
        //Next Faucet here
   ]
   },
   
  {"name": "ETHcoin",
  "shorthand": "ETH",
  "faucets": [
        {"faucetname":"eth Faucet",
        "minutes": "5",
        "reward": "~10000",
        "claim": "http://ethwebsite.com"},
    ]
 }
]
```

**datatable**

```html
<table id="faucetlist" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>faucet name</th>
                <th>Minutes</th>
                <th>reward</th>
                <th>Claim</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>      
        </tfoot>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        </table>  
</div>
```

also **javascript** here

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#faucetlist').DataTable();
      } );            
  </script>
```

Comment: So you wants to display data into datatables using ajax right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not define your columns or your data. 
Assign your JSON to a variable:

```
var data = {
..faucetlist JSON here
}
```

Example borrowed from: https://datatables.net/manual/data/

```
$('#faucetlist').DataTable( {
    data: data,
    columns: [
        { data: 'column-1' },
        { data: 'column-2' },
        { data: 'column-3' },
        { data: 'column-4' }
    ]
} );
```

I purposefully did not fill out the column names.

Comment: i try this with my it shows me just blank it also dont tell me how can i add 2 columns   as this is a faucet list that  i will put its own coin in its own page like bitcoin list eth list etc with tabs